# adding elements at identical keys in multiple multidimensional arrays

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm trying to do a web application with php and MySQL that can graph the estimate effort of a person based on the data stored in the data base

```
$luna_start = date('n',  strtotime($row_task['data_i']));
$luna_end   = date('n',  strtotime($row_task['data_s']));
$luna_curenta=$luna_start;
$ultimazi_luna_curenta=  cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $luna_curenta,"2012");
while ($luna_curenta<=$luna_end){
//construieste vectorul
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $ultimazi_luna_curenta; $i++) {
        $data_curenta=  date("Y-m-d", mktime(0, 0, 0, $luna_curenta, $i, 2012));
        if (($data_curenta>=$row_task['data_i'])&&($data_curenta<=$row_task['data_s'])){
            $efort_a['a'.$row_task['task_id']][$data_curenta]=$efort_mediu;
        }
    }
$luna_curenta++;
}
```

all that trouble for getting an array so that i can graph. the array $efort_a looks like this:

```
Array(
   [a19] => Array(
        [2012-09-20] => 2.84
        [2012-09-21] => 2.84
       .......
        [2012-10-21] => 2.84
        [2012-10-22] => 2.84
    )

[a22] => Array
    (
        [2012-10-01] => 0.1
        [2012-10-02] => 0.1
       .....
        [2012-11-05] => 0.1
        [2012-11-06] => 0.1
        [2012-11-07] => 0.1
      ......
        [2012-11-25] => 0.1
      ......
        [2012-11-30] => 0.1
    )

[a16] => Array
    (
        [2012-10-08] => 4
        [2012-10-09] => 4
        [2012-10-10] => 4
        [2012-10-11] => 4
       ......
        [2012-10-18] => 4
        [2012-10-19] => 4
    )

)
```

further more I'm doing a little more array processing.

```
extract($efort_a);
$graf_data=  array_add($a19,$a22,$a16);
$data = new GoogleChartData($graf_data);
$chart->addData($data);
```

the problem with all this code is that it isn't a dynamic one. the arrays a19, a22, a16 are named statically and in this particular case the user had only 3 tasks (task id 19, 22 and 16) ... but what if the user has multiple tasks ?.

1. so the questions is can this code be reorganized, maybe as a function i don't know how, to be a dynamic one ?
2. could it be possible to do a function that graph's all the users effort (one graph, multiple lines- one for each user)

ps: the function to do the adding of arrays based on keys is:

```
 function array_add($a1, $a2) {
            // adds the values at identical keys together
            $aRes = $a1;
            foreach (array_slice(func_get_args(), 1) as $aRay) {
              foreach (array_intersect_key($aRay, $aRes) as $key => $val) $aRes[$key] += $val;
              $aRes += $aRay; 
             }
            return $aRes;
    }
```

========================================= day 2 =======================

after some thinking i thought to give another try... so in order to name the keys of array effort_a dynamically i need to know where to stop with the incrementation so :

```
$sql_nrtask='SELECT *, COUNT(user) AS nr_task
                FROM task
                WHERE user="ASD"
                ORDER BY data_i ASC
               ';
    $query_nrtask=  mysql_query($sql_nrtask) or die ('rrr');
    while ($row_nrtask=  mysql_fetch_array($query_nrtask)) {
        $nr_task=$row_nrtask['nr_task']; // no we know how many sub-arrays we'll have
    }
for ($j++;$j<=$nr_task;$j++){
while ($luna_curenta<=$luna_end){
            //construieste vectorul
            for ($i = 1; $i <= $ultimazi_luna_curenta; $i++) {
                $data_curenta=  date("Y-m-d", mktime(0, 0, 0, $luna_curenta, $i, 2012));
                if (($data_curenta>=$row_task['data_i'])&&($data_curenta<=$row_task['data_s'])){
                    $efort_a['$a'.$j][$data_curenta]=$efort_mediu;
                }
            }
            $luna_curenta++;
        }
}
```

the problem is know that i don't know hot to merge the arrays within $efort_a with 2 conditions:

- keeping indexes where they are the same and adding values
- adding a new index where it is a new element